# Getting Json data from API and Displaying only part of the json in Unity C#

Tags: c#, json, api, unity-game-engine, json.net

I'm having trouble getting just the price value from [this API](https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/XBT.json). I don't need all the JSON that's coming from the web URL, I only need the `"rate":"3,394.2033"` part.

API Data:

```
{
  "time": {
    "updated": "Feb 6, 2019 22:02:00 UTC",
    "updatedISO": "2019-02-06T16:02:00-06:00",
    "updateduk": "Feb 6, 2019 at 22:02 GMT"
  },
  "disclaimer": "This data was produced from the CoinDesk Bitcoin Price Index (USD). Non-USD currency data converted using hourly conversion rate from openexchangerates.org",
  "bpi": {
    "USD": {
      "code": "USD",
      "rate": "3,394.2033",
      "description": "United States Dollar",
      "rate_float": 3394.2033
    },
    "XBT": {
      "code": "XBT",
      "rate": "1.0000",
      "description": "Bitcoin",
      "rate_float": 1
    }
  }
}
```

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class API : MonoBehaviour
{
    private string www = 
    "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/XBT.json";
    public Text responseText;

    public void Request()
    {
        WWW request = new WWW(www);
        StartCoroutine(OnResponse(request));
    }
    private IEnumerator OnResponse(WWW req)
    {
        yield return req;

        responseText.text = req.text;
    }
}
```

This script allows me to pull all the JSON data but I only need the `"rate":"3,394.2033"`. More specifically, just the value `3,394.2033`.

Answer (score 1):

Using Json.Net's [LINQ-to-JSON API](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) (JTokens) you can do this with one line of code:

```
var rate = (string)JToken.Parse(json).SelectToken("bpi.USD.rate");
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Krgejr

Comment: Nice, didn't know that one! Looks like an equivalent alternative to [SimpleJSON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54567729/7111561)

Comment: Thanks! Ended up getting it working tinkering around with this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use newtonsoft and follow this example here : https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSONFragments.htm

```
public class SearchResult
{
    public string Rate { get; set; }
}


JObject rateSearch = JObject.Parse(MyJsonText);

// get JSON result objects into a list
IList<JToken> results = rateSearch ["bpi"]["USD"].Children().ToList();

// serialize JSON results into .NET objects
IList<SearchResult> searchResults = new List<SearchResult>();
foreach (JToken result in results)
{
    // JToken.ToObject is a helper method that uses JsonSerializer internally
    SearchResult searchResult = result.ToObject<SearchResult>();
    searchResults.Add(searchResult);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the direction ;), with this example, how does this line of code get the Title, Content, and URL from the example link from Newtonsoft? `IList<JToken> results = rateSearch ["responseData"]["results"].Children().ToList();`

Comment: I edit my answer with your example : rateSearch ["bpi"]["USD"].Children().ToList(); . You can see your json formatted here : https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the old but gold [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) from the Unity community

> To use SimpleJSON in Unity you just have to copy the SimpleJSON.cs file into your projects "plugins" folder inside your assets folder.

and do e.g.

```
var json = JSON.Parse(req.text);
var yourText = json["bpi"]["USD"]["rate"];
```

---

Note for debugging

If the given key wasn't found in contrary to what you would expect this returns `null` instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UnityWebRequest.Get to get the JSON and then use a library to deserialize it (I'd recommend NewtonSoft.Json).

After deserializing the JSON you can choose which properties to use from the resulting object.

I put together a tutorial doing just that and a bit more.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yp8uPxEn6Vg